# Secure Web app by user credential and secure REST API within app via best secure method in spring security

Tags: java

I have a web application which has a single page AngularJS and Spring Security.application going to login via HTTP basic and Hibernate.

My application has a REST API. Now how do I secure my REST API call after a successfully login in Spring Security.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I think this is a bit broad, and more on-topic on [SO]. However, if you want to post there, be sure to include the code that you already have - then ask if it is secure. You could also ask this on [CodeReview.SE], but _don't_ post on both - we don't like cross-posting here. Good luck!